# Which set do these LEGO bricks belong to?

Tags: set-identification

Please help me identify which LEGO set do these blocks belong to.

[image]

Comment: Codes found on the bags are, usually, entirely irrelevant to set number. Please look into making pictures of your bags and bricks and uploading them here.

Comment: Please help now..

Comment: Looks like one of the four Naboo Starfighters, doesn't it? But which one...

Comment: Parts match this set: [75092 Naboo Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75092-1&name=Naboo%20Starfighter&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%201%5D#T=I) (bricklink)

Comment: The [Stick 6M W/Flange in bright yellow ](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6109813) clearly identifies this as [75092](https://brickset.com/sets/75092-1)

Answer (score 6):

As already identified in the comments by Uli, the parts [Stick 6M W/Flange in bright yellow](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6109813) and [Brick 4X6 W/Bow/Angle in bright yellow](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4180483) are only available together in [75092-1: Naboo Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75092-1): [image: 75092-1: Naboo Starfighter]

Comment: I find TLG color naming confusing, so a little clarification here: Bright Yellow [TLG], Yellow [BL]